# C++: 2 memory areas, one protected and one not. If class B in unprotected area calls class A in protected area directly an error should be thrown

Tags: c++, interface, embedded, constexpr

Environment:

- embedded, so not much overhead allowed
- no heap
- not much space
- component (class) A and B is in "protected" memory area 1
- component (class) C is in memory area 2
- A and B is it allowed to use each other directly
- It is not allowed for C to use directly A and B. This should be done centralized, over an interface or something else. Maybe I could not imagine yet (this is more or less the question)

Problem:

1. Is there maybe an elegant way to provide an interface for classes in
   memory area 1 to be called from classes in memory are 2
2. Is there a way to check if class C uses class A directly without going over the interface. static_assert error?
3. Is there maybe an elegant way to place classes which should be in protected memory directly in at compile time

hopefully you got my point.

Comment: friend classes?

Comment: What would the interface provide extra over a direct pointer to the object?

Comment: What does "protected" mean? Protected flash? Protected by MMU/virtual memory? Some fuzzy "soft" protection?

Comment: Also, classes don't "use each other" in some generic sense, they either contain other classes or inherit other classes. They are not procedures. So it is kind of pointless to speak of some generic A, B and C because it isn't obvious how/if this design makes any sense to begin with. Is there an application layer or is the whole program existing in these 3 fuzzy classes?

Comment: Overall start with use cases and specification. When that's been iterated through a couple of times and make sense, then you can worry about program design and choice of programming language next. C++ is quite unsuitable for most restricted microcontroller applications, so you need to consider if there's some actual rationale behind the choice of programming language, or if it's just what some PC programmer told you to use.

Comment: Does "protected" in this question refer to the C++ `protected` keyword or to some other concept of memory protection ?

Comment: @Botje: There is no extra feature. It is just prescribed to use a bottleneck when you use functionality from Memory area 2 in Memory area 1 and the other way around. Please dont think about the sense of these. It makes no sense in the end, but it is prescribed to have it

Comment: @Lundin Protected mean, that there is prescribed that there has to be a so called bottleneck between those two areas. When functionality from memory are 1 is needed in memory are 2 there has to be a centralized interface. As mentioned above please dont think about the sense in this case. It makes no sense but is prescribed. Protected also mean, that there has to be made a checksum over the entire ROM in Memory area 1. So when you add functionality in memory area 2, this checksum from memory area 1 should not change.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner No the keyword protected from c++ has nothing to do with this. Pleas refer to the answer to Lundin. There I described what protected means

Comment: Just to mention. If a function from Memory area 2 calls a function from memory area1 not over the centralized interface I need a compile time error. And of course the other way around.